# What happens when the DC supply of this common gate amplifier is switched off?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, common-gate

The Vin in this case is a 200 mV peak to peak sine wave signal. What happens to the gain of the amplifier when the DC supply of 10V is switched off?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the DC supply to the amplifier is switched off, there would be no source of output current to the 10k load resistor.  Therefore the output voltage would be zero so that the gain of the amplifier would also be zero.

Comment: If Vdd drops to 0, much of the circuit becomes dead. You could argue there's a capacitor coupling between Vin and Vout through the ground node. I think at that point, at frequency, Vout = Vin + Voffset. Since gain is Vout/Vin, the gain is technically 1. It's not really an amplifier at this point.

Comment: Switched off could also mean disconnected, not shorted.